# Directional derivative into the begining...

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Hey guys another try to do a Directional derivative,
i want to do a Directional derivative of $z= x^2*e^{2x+3y}$ at $(2,-1)$ to the begining $$(0,0)$$
This is what ive done:

so the vector will be $$u=(-2,1)$$ so the vector normal is $(\frac{-2}{\sqrt5},\frac{1}{\sqrt5})$
$$Z_x=2xe^{2x+3y} +2x^2 e^{2x+3y}$$
$$Z_y=3x^2e^{2x+3y}$$
which means that we get $$(\frac{12}{e},\frac{12}{e})$$
so we get the Directional derivative to be $$\frac{-2}{\sqrt5}*\frac{12}{e} +\frac{1}{\sqrt5}*\frac{12}{e}=\frac{12}{\sqrt5e}$$
have i done it correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$z(x,y)=x^2e^{2x+3y}\implies\nabla z(x,y)=\left(2xe^{2x+3y}+2x^2e^{2x+3y}\,,\,\,3x^2e^{2x+3y}\right)\implies$$

$$\nabla(-2,1)=\left(\frac4e\;,\;\;\frac{12}e\right)$$

and the direction is $\;u:=(0,0)-(-2,1)=(2,-1)\;$ , so

$$D_u(z)(-2,1)=\left(\frac4e,\,\frac{12}e\right)\cdot\frac1{\sqrt5}(2,-1)=-\frac4{e\sqrt5}$$

Comment: I typed it wrong the point was (2,-1), (edited just now)so what ive done is correct?(since its the same?)
Thanks!

Comment: @user152711 Yup, then it looks correct.